# What will be the most suitable settings in .gitignore file for Wordpress project?

Tags: wordpress, git

When using git with Wordpress project, what will be recommended settings for .gitignore file?

Comment: GitHub suggests: https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/main/WordPress.gitignore

Answer (score 21):

This is from [GitHub's help files](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/WordPress.gitignore):

```
*.log
.htaccess
sitemap.xml
sitemap.xml.gz
wp-config.php
wp-content/advanced-cache.php
wp-content/backup-db/
wp-content/backups/
wp-content/blogs.dir/
wp-content/cache/
wp-content/upgrade/
wp-content/uploads/
wp-content/wp-cache-config.php
```

Comment: Why is the `wp-config.php` file ignored?

Comment: I imagine it's because your development config is different from your other developers development config which again is nothing like the production config, so no point tracking it's changes

Comment: It's better to write `/.htaccess` to ignore just the root level .htaccess file, otherwise it will ignore `admin\.htaccess` and others. Someone pulling your repo will have a hard time figuring out they are missing .htaccess files in some obscure subfolder.

Comment: that file says something completely different

Answer (score 14):

Posting this as an answer because it seems I can't comment on answers.

I suggest the following (based on Dales answer):

```sh
.htaccess
wp-config.php
wp-content/*
!wp-content/themes/
!wp-content/plugins/
sitemap.xml
*.log
sitemap.xml
sitemap.xml.gz
```

What it does is that it first ignores everything within wp-content but then makes exceptions for the wp-content/themes/ and wp-content/plugins/ folders.

Comment: I like this answer and I think it makes sense to take it one step further and exclude all plugins and themes by default, only including those that are whitelisted.